# input type submit onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to find reference if it is possible to add text to onmouseover

So for this I'd like to add just a simple tip for onmouseover of the "Monitor" button.

```
<input type="submit" name="video" value="Monitor" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`title`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_title.asp) attribute.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `title` as JRL said and if you want something more advanced, here's a list of some god tooltip scripts : http://dzineblog.com/2008/10/30-tooltips-scripts.html

Answer (score 2):

Simple HTML will do it:

```
<input type="submit" title="Blah Blah Blah">
```

And if you want ***multiple lines***, just do this:

```
<input type="submit" title="Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah">
```

A working Demo: ***[`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/DPMNK/`](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/DPMNK/)***

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="submit" name="video" value="Monitor" title="My text" />
```